Тропы и формулы в художественных произведениях: одно слово с двумя значениями или разные понятия?
Скажите, пожалуйста, тропы (средства художественной выразительности) и тропы — формулы, используемые автором в художественных произведениях (выражения и словосочетания типа «Великолепный мерзавец», «А двести двадцать не хочешь?», «А для меня это был вторник»), — это одно и то же слово с двумя значениями или разные?

В качестве версии
Вероятно, этот вопрос рассматривается в каких-то источниках, я же могу предложить свой вариант ответа.

Троп и формула-троп — это близкие понятия, но не тождественные, так как у них может быть разный статус.

Троп в общем случае — это перенос значений по сходству, смежности, количественным характеристикам и т. д. (без прямого сравнения). Иначе говоря, это использование слов и выражений в переносном значении для создания художественного образа.
Формула-троп использует те же средства, но характеризует ситуацию в целом, когда она понятна пользователям. А это уже скорее мем, то есть словосочетание или предложение, которое применимо к подобным ситуациям.
Мем обладает вирусностью, это его основное свойство. И мы получаем уже сходство по ситуации, но при этом  формула-троп основана на сравнении в обычном понимании.

Пример: А для меня это был вторник.
— Мой отец спас свою деревню ценой собственной жизни. Ты 
застрелил его, когда убегал. Герой с расстояния в тысячу 
шагов.
— ...Прости. Я ничего из этого не помню.
— Ты не помнишь?!
— Для вас день, когда  я  украсил вашу деревню, был самым 
важным днем в вашей жизни. Но для меня это был вторник.



Ситуация понятна. Для одного персонажа день становится поворотным в жизни, а для другого это просто день.  Переносное значение основано на сравнении: вторник — это  обыкновенный и ничем не примечательный день.

Тропы, тропы...  Вероятно, лингвисты изучают только ЗАПЯТЫЕ, ведь других версий нет.  А  по большому счету стилистика художественной речи должна бы их интересовать...

А что такое формула-троп? Мне, если честно, нигде не встречалось подобное понятие.

Серж, этот термин предложил автор вопроса, и я его тоже использую. Такой прием речи существует, поэтому надо как-то его назвать. Если эта тема где-то обсуждалась, то, возможно, там было другое название.
